# BibTex Referncing Number order based on appearence

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, errors, sorting

Today while i tried to add bibliography in bibtex I found problems with sorting like the figure
[image]
How to solve this kind of error .. I tried to sort based on appearance but failed .. What should i add to get rid of it

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.7in,headsep=12pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}
.
.
.
.
.
.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Moreover it is showing some errors shown in the figure. How to debug them? 
[image]

Please suggest me to make an error free reference based on the appearance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The `numeric` style by default creates labels that are sorted by author name. If you want labels sorted by appearance in the document body, use

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Regarding the errors shown in your log, you should ask a new question and provide a minimal working (compilable) example.